# (PostgreSQL 11) Reading in an array of JSON objects (or composite types) from a CSV file into Postgres

Tags: postgresql, json, array, csv, composite-types

So I am trying to import rows into a table using a CSV file, but have been running into problems I haven't been able to solve. I would like one column of a row to be an array of JSON objects.

**How I would generally like my table to look like:**

| statement_id INT | statement VARCHAR(100) | options JSON[] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | I am cool | [{label: 'Not true', value: 1}, {label: 'Somewhat True', value: 2}, {label: 'Very true', value: 3}] |

I am choosing to not create a separate table for the *options* because there's really no need for me to do so in my application, so I would like to not have to do that if possible.

**My definition of the table:**

```
CREATE TABLE statements(
statement_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
statement VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
options JSON [],
PRIMARY KEY(statement_id)
);
```

**How I import the CSV file into the table:**

```
copy statements(statement_id, statement, options)
from 'D:\Projects\project\files\statements.csv'
delimiter ','
csv header;
```

**How *options* is formatted in my CSV:**

```
{("label": "Not at all True","value": 1),("label": "Hardly True","value": 2),("label": "Moderately True","value": 3),("label": "Exactly True","value": 4)}
```

**Attempt 1**

Using the setup I've mentioned above, this is the error I get:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "{("label": "Not at all True","value": 1),("label": "Hardly True","value": 2),("label": "Moderately True","value": 3),("label": "Exactly True","value": 4)}"
DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
CONTEXT:  COPY asmt_questions, line 2, column options: "{("label": "Not at all True","value": 1),("label": "Hardly True","value": 2),("label": "Moderately T..."
```

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087380/postgresql-unexpected-array-element), and edited my *options* format in the CSV to be:

```
array[("label": "Not at all True","value": 1),("label": "Hardly True","value": 2),("label": "Moderately True","value": 3),("label": "Exactly True","value": 4)]::json[]
```

and got the following error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "array[("label": "Not at all True","value": 1),("label": "Hardly True","value": 2),("label": "Moderately True","value": 3),("label": "Exactly True","value": 4)]::json[]"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
CONTEXT:  COPY asmt_questions, line 2, column options: "array[("label": "Not at all True","value": 1),("label": "Hardly True","value": 2),("label": "Moderat..."
```

**Attempt 2**

I couldn't find any solutions that were related to this problem, but I did notice that the solution I mentioned above used composite types, so I created a composite type:

```
CREATE TYPE statement_option AS (
    label VARCHAR(20),
    value INT
);
```

and changed the *statement* table schema to be

```
CREATE TABLE statements(
    statement_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    statement VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    options statement_option [],
    PRIMARY KEY(statement_id)
    );
```

I got the same errors listed above.

**Attempt n**

After trying to search for a solution to these errors, I couldn't find one that was specific to this situation (a lot of them had to do with procedures and functions). So I tried many different combinations of the above setups.

I tried using brackets to represent an array in the CSV (ex: `[{},{}]`), I changed the `[]` to `ARRAY` in the *statement* table schema, I used single quotes instead of double quotes in the CSV file, etc. All to no avail.

At this point, I feel like I've exhausted the options I can try when it comes to this specific setup. I have a hunch that I might have to just do it line by line, or just create a procedure to read them in.

But I was wondering if there was something that I'm missing, or something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the warm welcome and for some direction! This was a very interesting solution and something new for me to try, so I'll definitely be playing around with the solution to fit my needs. I'll respond to my own post if I find a solution. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd be interested in your solution - leave a comment for me under this one and please put '@' and my 'handle' (i.e. '@Vérace') in the body of the comment so that I'm sure to see it.

Comment: @Vérace The answer below was able to provide me a solution before I came up with one using the link/method you sent me! I basically restructured my CSV file so the delimiter was a semicolon (interestingly, I couldn't find a way to do this without changing the delimiter to all my files, so I just did it manually for my one file), made sure the CSV looked like the one in the answer, and used their copy statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

My CSV

```
id;json
1;{"{\"label\": \"Not at all True\",\"value\": 1}","{\"label\": \"Hardly True\",\"value\": 2}","{\"label\": \"Moderately True\",\"value\": 3}","{\"label\": \"Exactly True\",\"value\": 4}"}
2;{"{\"label\": \"Not at all True\",\"value\": 1}","{\"label\": \"Hardly True\",\"value\": 2}","{\"label\": \"Moderately True\",\"value\": 3}","{\"label\": \"Exactly True\",\"value\": 4}"}
```

My Table:

```
create table test_json_list (id integer, j json[]);
```

My COPY statement:

```
COPY test_json_list (id, j) FROM '/tmp/json.csv' WITH (DELIMITER ';', HEADER, FORMAT CSV, QUOTE '|');
```

Explanation:
The array literal in PostgresSQL is a list of elements between curly braces, ex: {1,2,3} or {'a','b','c'}

I didn't find a clear explanation in the docs of the reason why the `COPY` command wants to have the JSON array elements quoted in double quotes, just took the output of a `COPY TO` command as reference.

I added a separator that doesn't conflict much with your JSON, but it is not very important.

I added a pipe QUOTE character to avoid one additional level of escaping of double quotes that would otherwise be required as the default CSV quote character is also a double quote.

My suggestion to simplify all this slightly would be to import a JSON array instead of an ARRAY (Postgres array) of JSONs if possible by your application logic.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you for your answer and explanation!